# How can I rename sub-properties of property type of JsonProperty in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I have implemented that stuff for first-level object properties when serializing using custom `ContractResolver` like here:

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    foreach (p in properties)
    {
       p.PropertyName = "any_new_name";
    }

    return properties;
}
```

But sometimes I need go deeper for renaming nested properties. How it is possible to do? Using recursive `CreateProperties`?

For example, I have to serialize an object

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public int Bar1 { get; set; }

    public Bar Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

where `Bar` is

```
public class GetReportDataViewModel
{
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }

    public int Bar21 { get; set; }
}
```

So, I expect result as something like

```
  {
    "any_new_name": "str_value",
    "any_new_name": int_value,
    "any_new_name": {
       "any_new_name": "str_value",
       "any_new_name": int_value
      }
  }
```

Comment: you can try dynamic object creation

Comment: Why don't you want to tune all of them using `JsonProperty` attribute?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that stuff for tuples, actually. however, I found solution

Comment: @anatol Then `JObject` class will be helpful:)

Comment: If you want to rename the properties of `Bar` *only within the context of `DTO`*, you cannot do it only with attributes on `DTO`.  You will need to use a `JsonConverter` or surrogate property.  Or do you want your custom contract resolver to rename the properties of `Bar` unconditionally and consistently?  If so, that's doable inside `CreateProperties()`.

Comment: @anatol if you found a solution, you should answer your own post